# No dirs in imported SBT project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala

After importing sbt project there are no dirs in project tree but I see them if I click on root dir in path

[image: In left tree no dirs for projects]

Comment: Are you able to run the project from command line?

Comment: When i try to run it I've got [error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
It is ok because in src there is only test dir with tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Source location of your code and delete `.idea` folder and also the `target` folder then try to open the project again.

Make sure you closed the project in Intellij IDEA before doing the above.